# tADA not reflecting in wallet after funds request with faucet

Tags: cardano-cli

As hinted by the title, I've requested 1000 tAda from the faucet and [according to what's here](https://explorer.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io/de/address?address=addr_test1qq7j49kq79ylyx5u8ns40gjd0g8s6l87hjxycuyhmvcvzlmhewza0tqpf5f25lsaa5nacluvvcuh9cr4lpeyswwdjz9swj5mkf) the funds is in the wallet.

But when I query the address on my testnet, it returns no result.

What am I possibly missing?

Comment: If one of the output address matches your wallet address, then most probably your node is not fully synchronised.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen yesterday and been troubleshooting since. Turned out my node was technically "synced" but spitting out errors in the log. (above 90%) I have a question out there about the error but have a hunch its because I need to update the cli/node to the latest verified release. Which I'm doing now. Below I outline a method you can use to run and verify your node is running properly. Pre-reqs is you already have the node dependencies installed as outlined in the dev portal.

If you want to see the logs I use nohup and "&" to run the node in the background (On linux, I'm running Debian). I put my cardano-node command in a script like this and name the file run-node.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

cardano-node run \
   --topology $YOURPATH/cardano/testnet-topology.json \
   --database-path $YOURPATH/cardano/db \
   --socket-path $YOURPATH/cardano/db/node.socket \
   --host-addr 0.0.0.0 \
   --port 1337 \
   --config $YOURPATH/cardano/testnet-config.json
```

Then you make sure the file is executable by running

```
chmod +x ./run-node.sh
```

Then you can run your script and get logs using this command...

```
nohup ./run-node.sh &
```

Then you can just run the following to check the logs and verify if there are any errors. (Ctrl-C to exit)

```
tail -f nohup.out
```

Oh and if you want to kill that process you can run

```
ps -aux
```

which will lay out all your processes. Use the PID of your cardano-node command and kill the process. Simple way to do that is to run

```
kill -9 $YOUR_PROCESS_PID
```

Sorry if this answer is a little overkill.

Comment: For anyone wondering, this problem did resolve itself after I updated the node and CLI to the latest verified release.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is look up the transaction on the testnet explorer.
https://explorer.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io/en.html

It should have given you the transaction id from the faucet after you made the tAda request.

If you find that transaction on the explorer, it should tell you how many
confirmations have been completed. 30 confirmations are required for a transaction to be fully processed. Only then will the UTxO show up in your wallet.

If there have been 30 confirmations, then you can lookup your wallet address on the explorer and see if it has been updated.

If you can see the UTxO in your wallet on the explorer, then it should be queryable with cardano-cli, as long as your node is synced. At this point, if you can't see the UTxO in your wallet using the cardano-cli after a few minutes, then it means there is a problem with your node.

If there is a problem with your node, then make sure you are using the correct version. The testnet currently requires cardano-node v1.30.1

You can check which version you are running by typing `cardano-node --version` from the bash shell.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case, are you querying the right testnet?

- testnet explorer https://explorer.cardano-testnet.iohkdev.io/
- alonzo purple explorer: https://explorer.alonzo-purple.dev.cardano.org/en.html

If you are following alonzo-testnet program, maybe you are not querying the right testnet.